# My async actions endlessly called in my react redux toolkit slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My Redux-async function endlessly called and hangs my system when i subscribe to the store using useSelector.

My Product.Slice

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

    import { apiCallBegan } from './../../app/store/api/api.action';
    const productSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'product',
        initialState: {
            products: [],        
        },
        reducers: {                
            productsReceived: (state, action) => {
                state.products=action.payload
            }
        }
        
    })
    export const { addProducts,productsReceived } = productSlice.actions
    
    export const loadProducts = () => apiCallBegan({
        url: "/product/",
        method: "get",
        onSuccess: productsReceived.type
    })

    export const getProducts = (state) => state.product.products


    export default productSlice.reducer
```

ProductList.js Use Reducer implementation:

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch(loadProducts())
    const products=useSelector(state=>state.product.products)
    console.log(products)
```

Comment: where dispatch(loadProducts()) called?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the problem:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(loadProducts());
const products = useSelector(
  (state) => state.product.products
);
console.log(products);
```

That is in a component that re renders when products change while also changing the products. Maybe you can only get the products on mount:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
React.useEffect(() => dispatch(loadProducts()), [
  dispatch,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you.. Its working now. My problem was, whenever i subscribe to te store using useSelector, endless async call started